# How to fill an inline-block div with a solid color?

Tags: html, css

Consider the code below. My intent was to have a green bar, `30px` wide, between `hello` and `world`.

```css
.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello <div class="bar"></div> world
</div>
```

The block is indeed there, but not filled in. What is missing?

Comment: there is no height (30x0)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: ahhh, thank you. I thought that the `div` would inherit the height of the line, being inline.

Comment: if you make the parent div `display:flex` it will : https://jsfiddle.net/uwz82h7c/1/

Comment: or you make it `inline` and in this case it will work as you expected: https://jsfiddle.net/uwz82h7c/

Answer (score 4):

There's no content in the `div` so the height is `0px`.  You can set a `height` or use `&nbsp;` within the `div` to make it display.

Comment: Upvote for `<div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>`, which solves the issue.